# Assembly code not working, does not return result of function

Tags: assembly, riscv

I am a beginner at Assembly and am trying to create a Fibonacci function, I have spent several hours trying to find the errors in my code and fixed whatever I thought was wrong. But despite my best efforts the code isn't printing any output. Here is what I've done in RISC-V Assembly:

```
main:
    addi    x10, zero, 7       # Argument
    jal     x10, fib           # Call fib(x10)

    # Print the result
    li      x17, 1            # System call number for printing integer
    ecall

    # End the program  
    li      x17, 93             # System call number for program exit
    li      x10, 0              # Exit with status 0
    ecall

fib:
    bne     x10, zero, elif    # Check if x10 == 0
    addi    x10, zero, 0       # Store 0 in x10
    jr      x10                # Return x10

elif:
    addi    x28, zero, 1       # Load 1 into x28
    bne     x10, x28, else     # Check if x10 == 1
    addi    x10, zero, 1       # Store 1 in x10
    jr      x10                # Return x10
else:
    addi    sp, sp, -8         # Adjust stack pointer
    sd      x10, 0(sp)         # Save x10

    addi    x10, x10, -2       # Compute x10 - 2
    jal     x10, fib           # Recursive call to fib(x10 - 2)
    mv      x29, x10           # Save result in x29

    ld      x10, 0(sp)         # Restore x10

    addi    x10, x10, -1       # Compute x10 - 1
    jal     x10, fib           # Recursive call to fib(x10 - 1)
    mv      x30, x10           # Save result in x30

    addi    sp, sp, 8          # Restore stack pointer
    add     x10, x29, x30      # Compute fib(x10 - 2) + fib(x10 - 1) and store in x10
    jr      x10                # Return x10
```

I would appreciate any guidance

Comment: If you have a debugger stepping through the code line by line will help a lot. alternately can you print a result from within fib()? This algorithm won't work with very small numbers. What is your input?

Comment: `jr x10 ` is wrong. You want `jr ra` or just `ret`. Also you need to save `ra` because the recursion will overwrite it.

Comment: @Jay my input is 7 which is stored in x10 and represents the index of the fib number. The function is supposed to return 13. The algorithm should work because in C++, the algorithm does produce the correct output when given 7.

Comment: I think the 1 ecall is putc, i.e. it prints an ascii character, not an integer. Also, the jalr x10, fib instruction will ovetwrite x10 before the call  - use ra  return address register instead.

Comment: I believe that the jal x10,fib plus the jr x10 is fine on its own, but what you are saying is use x10 as the return value.  but you are changing x10 corrupting the return address.  Normally one would say jal fib and ret, which implies ra as the return register.  if you do not do another jal then you do not need to preserve ra.  (but you do have a jal so you need to preserve ra on the stack and restore it before the ret).

Comment: you need to not try to write a whole application in one shot,  write a number of throwaway programs each with a learning exercise, for example call a function and return a value.   call a function preserve ra on the stack, restore it (and return a value)  call a function, preserve ra, call another function, etc etc....Looks like this was not written incrementally.